# Mathematical proofs with Cardinality

Tags: proof-writing

1. Prove that for any natural number $n$, $n<$ the cardinality of continuum.
2. Prove that Cardinality of the power sets of the naturals < the cardinality of the power set if the reals.
3. Prove that there is no largest cardinal number.
4. Prove that if there is a function f:A->the naturals that is injective, then A is countable

PLEASE HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. What do we know?  We know that if $A \subseteq B$, then the cardinality of $A$ is less than that of $B$.  If $A$ and $B$ are finite and the inequality is exact, then the inequality with regard to cardinality is exact as well.  So, what happens if we choose $A$ to have cardinality $n$.  Can we have $B$ with cardinality $n+1$ but $B$ still being a subset of the continuum?  If so, how does this help us?
2. Is it true that if $A\subseteq B$, then the power set of $A$ is a subset of the power set of $B$?  How does this give us the result?
3. Given a set $A$, is there a way you can think of which allows you to create a set $A^{+}$ with the cardinality of $A^{+}$ strictly greater than that of $A$?  Perhaps consider the power set.  Would this work? Why?
4. Well, if $f$ is an injection, then $A$ is  in bijection with a subset of the natural numbers.  Are subsets of countable sets countable?

Comment: Unfortunately, I Need A Little More Help Then Just That..

Comment: On what specifically would you like more elaboration?  Since you didn't give your thoughts on how to do it I tried to just give you hints so that you could still find the answers for yourself.  Hint: If I ask you if you can do something, the answer is yes.